# Quality and Track selection controls in Azure Media Player

Tags: azure-media-services

We're trying to implement the Azure Media Player into our site. I've noticed in some samples the azure media play can have a track selection and bit-rate controls.

For example http://ampdemo.azureedge.net/

How do we get them to appear in our player? I can't see this as a configuration option in the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't quite a configuration for the player. Rather, it's a menu that is displayed when the platform and type of content supports adaptive multibitrate streaming. if you set up an adaptive AMS stream to playback in a modern browser it should show up automatically. Let me know if this makes sense/if you have more questions on how to use Azure Media Services and AMP.

Comment: Hi @sraje, that sort of makes sense. We have a mix of multi bit-rate MP4's  and Smooth Streaming assets that we are trying to play. Some of the new Smooth Streaming assets are setup for Dynamic Packaging and Encryption. If i play content using the Smooth Streaming locator then these controls should appear right? At least for the dynamic ones, static ones might have been encoded to a single bit-rate. Would this work on the Multibitrate MP4's?

Comment: For you smooth streaming manifest (ends with .ism/manifest) it really depends on if you have flash enabled. if you do, the icon should display, if you're playing back  via the Silverlight plugin. then it will not. Either way, the icon only shows up if you're playing media services streaming manifests that end in .ism/manifest (smooth) or .ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf) (dash)

Comment: I believe we are just using silverlight to play smooth streaming with playready protection. Does the silverlight player not support these controls?

Comment: it does not. What browser/platform are you playing back on? If it's modern you should be able to use AzureHtml5JS to playback Playready or Widevine.

Comment: So this is just for testing playback of assets, Our normal player is a silverlight player, so we need to test SmoothStreaming with PlayReady. But we can also test the Multibitrate MP4's that are used for Dynamic Packaging/Encryption. Later on we will probably expand to a HTML5. I See Microsoft Edge should support HTML5 + PlayReady but at the moment i get "No compatible source was found for this media" when trying to play. I suspect there is something wrong with my config.

Comment: interesting, feel free to email me at saraje@microsoft.com with your repro URL and I can take a closer look at your config.